# Using locks to access a method in C#

Tags: c#, locks

I have a method A which call another method B.  Upon clicking on a button, method A is called which in turn calls method B.  However, when 2 users click on the button simultaneously, I want only one user to access method B while the other waits for method B to complete.  I thought of doing it this way:

```
private static Object _Lock = new Object();

private void A(){
  lock(_Lock){
     B();
  }
}
```

The users are on different machines. The project is a web site.

But I think this is not correct.   How can I improve the above code so that it is the proper way to work?

Comment: You mean, on different machines? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Is `B()` a service call perhaps?  I think you may have overgeneralised your question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman: the users are on different machines.  The project is a web site.

Comment: @JamesThorpe:  B() is not a service call but a method.

Comment: OK.  In that case, how long does `B` take?  Are you willing to let your users queue up while it happens with no response to them?  What makes you think what you have is not correct?

Comment: Yes, I think I will let the users queue up in the meantime.  B is a very short method.  I am not sure that just adding lock(_Lock) before calling B in A is going to allow only one user at a time to access B().

Comment: Does the functions are in a shared class (Singleton for example) or on a static class or different threads?

Comment: @Liron the functions are in the same class.

Comment: I meant does this class is shared among threads - meaning multiple users are taking an instance (Singleton) of the class and then every thing is shared among the threads or you create a new instance every time (`MyClass A = new MyClass())` or just using static methods?

Comment: @Liron: It is shared among threads.

Comment: Try to design around this. Single access methods on websites aren't really going to work. If you need to enforce serial access, it may work better down at a database level, if you have one. Even then, it goes against the tenets of web development where you *should* be able to scale out across multiple servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Torestergaard, you should keep the lock as slim as possible. Therefor if taking the code sample provided above by @Rebornx and modifying it a bit you can use something like below example:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        LockSample lockSampleInstance = LockSample.GetInstance();
        lockSampleInstance.MethodA();
    }
}

public class LockSample
{
    private static readonly LockSample INSTANCE = new LockSample();
    private static Object lockObject = new Object();

    public static LockSample GetInstance()
    {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("MethodA Called");
       MethodB();
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
        lock(lockObject)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MethodB Called");      
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help,
Liron

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program, I used single ton pattern. You can achieve the locking by using "Monitor" also.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        LockSample lockObject = LockSample.GetInstance();
        lock(lockObject)
        {
          lockObject.MethodA();
        }
    }
}

public class LockSample
{
    private static LockSample _Lock;
    public static LockSample GetInstance()
    {
       if(_Lock == null)
       {
          _Lock = new LockSample();
       }
       return _Lock;
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
       Console.WriteLine("MethodA Called");
       MethodB();
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("MethodB Called");      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should keep you lock as slim as possible, so dependent on what you do then it might make sense to move the lock statement into method B only guarding the resource that doesn't support multiple parallel users.

But generally there is nothing wrong with your example.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the method B with this attribute:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
public void B() {
   ...
}
```